# TestNG won't build/run tests in a Netbeans Java Modular Project

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, testng, java-module

I created a new project in Apache Netbeans 10 using the option "Java Modular Project", created a module, copied existing source packages into the module's "classes" tree, and copied existing test packages (which use the TestNG frameork) into the "tests" tree. With the dependencies configured, and the module-info.java file adjusted suitably, no errors show, and "Clean and Build Project" reports no errors.

But I cannot get any of my TestNG tests to execute. Right-clicking on a single test class and selecting "Test" or "Run" causes nothing to happen at all. And right-clicking on my master test suite XML file and selecting "Test" causes the following to appear on the console (paths contracted for easier reading):

```
/home/.../ProjectName/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1629: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/.../ProjectName/nbproject/build-impl.xml:557: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/.../ProjectName/nbproject/build-impl.xml:544: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/.../ProjectName/nbproject/build-impl.xml:495: /home/.../ProjectName/build/test/classes does not exist.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Why the build process is referring to `build/test/classes` I don't know, because it looks like a Java modular project uses the path `build/test/modules` (at least that's what I see when I use the Files window to check the directory structure).

These tests all ran fine in Netbeans 8 using a non-modular Java project, so the problem is not in the tests themselves.

Is the build/run process for TestNG known to be broken in Netbeans where modular Java projects are involved, or am I doing something wrong in the creation and configuration of this modular project?

Update: recreating the entire project in Netbeans 10 as a Maven project, the build and test actions do cause the TestNG test classes to compile and execute. So I believe this to be a problem with the Ant build scripts used by Netbeans 10 for modular Java projects.

Comment: And before you ask: I need a modular project because I need to import the new `java.net.http` module made available in JDK 11.

Comment: This could be possible because of the test modules build with a modular project. Though the error shared by you merely has some information. Maybe someone from netbeans can pitch in to help.

Comment: Yeah, I've posted the same question to the [Apache Netbeans Users Mailing List](https://netbeans.apache.org/community/mailing-lists.html) but no reply so far. It's possibly something I was doing wrong, but my suspicion is that the Ant build scripts for modular projects simply don't work for TestNG. I've recreated my projects as Maven builds and the compilation and testing runs without any problems. So I've given up on Ant for now.